# Can't get divs to align properly with css

Tags: html, css, alignment

My setup is this:

```css
.cprp_data {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cprp_title {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.gelijkeniscore {
  float: right;
}

.cprp_percentage {
  float: right;
}

.cprp_excerpt {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.cprp-custom-container {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cprp_data">
  <div class="cprp_title">TITLE</div>
  <div class="gelijkeniscore">SOME CONTENT</div>
  <div class="cprp_percentage">SOME CONTENT</div>
  <div class="cprp_excerpt">SOME CONTENT</div>
  <div class="cprp-custom-container">SOME CONTENT IN SEVERAL DIVS
  </div>
</div>
```

cprp_data should function as the wrapper, and this is how i want the other divs inside it to to align:

```
<cprp_title> <gelijkeniscore>
<cprp_excerpt> <cprp_percentage>
               <cprp-custom-container>
```

To be clear, divs cprp_excerpt and cprp_title should align left on top of each other using a width of 80%, and the other 3 divs are supposed to align right also on top of each other using the remaining 20%, looking kinda like a sidebar.

I can't get it to work. Been trying for hours using several CSS setups. The above CSS is as close as i have gotten so far. But somehow the cprp_excerpt div keeps taking up 100% of the width pushing the cprp-custom-container way down. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have several typos in your code where you typed `80&` instead of `80%` I guess?. Also, add `width` to your different elements !

Comment: Is changing the markup out of the question? This would be easier if you could change the order of the markup to match the order in your output. OR if you could add a div around the two elements that go in reverse order you could use flexbox and flex-direction to flip them.

Comment: Changing the markup is tough as the output is generated by 2 different wordpress plugins. However i should be able to add a div by editing the php of one of the plugins.. Can you help me how and where i should add it?

Comment: what div's can you change in terms of order?

Comment: Every div except cprp-custom-container, that always comes last, as it is generated by a separate plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inferred from the problem statement:

- all the internal divs are now stacked upon each other in the desired hierarchy
- left container occupies 80% screen width
- right container occupies 20% screen width
- The container wrapper remains intact, i have just introduced two sub-wrappers to distinguish contents of left and right side of screen

Hope this code helps!

```css
.cprp_data {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* display flex to control the scenario */
  display: flex;
}

/*.cprp_title {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.gelijkeniscore {
  float: right;
}

.cprp_percentage {
  float: right;
}

.cprp_excerpt {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.cprp-custom-container {
  float: right;
}
*/
/* as the left section should be 80% in width */
.left{
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
/* as the right section should be 20% */
.right{
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cprp_data">
<div class="left">
  <div class="cprp_title">TITLE</div>
   <div class="cprp_excerpt">SOME CONTENT</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="gelijkeniscore">SOME CONTENT</div>
  <div class="cprp_percentage">SOME CONTENT</div>
 
  <div class="cprp-custom-container">SOME CONTENT IN SEVERAL DIVS
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: happy to assist you @njinok

Comment: Yes, no problem. However, how do i do that?

Comment: Clicked the checkmark and it became green. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

shift the cprp_percentage div after the cprp_excerpt div

Comment: That takes me halfway there. Thank you. However the cprp-custom-container div is still pushed all the way down aligning to the right below the cprp_excerpt div content. while i want it to align directly below the cprp_percentage div next to the cprp_excerpt div

Comment: Happy to help you